# Deployed Scaffold rails app to Heroku. "heroku open" gives "page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Windows 7, re-installed latest rails version from railsinstaller.org today.
"heroku push" was successful.
db migration successful.
"heroku open" gives "page you were looking for doesn't exist"

I've deployed before using Rails 4 and didn't have any problems. Just today.

Please help!

Thanks

Log:

```
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504807+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504807+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.505102+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.505102+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.504964+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.505102+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-23T21:15:17.505102+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T21:15:17.723887+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-gorge-3135.herokuapp.com fwd="162.195.72.6" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-08-23T22:20:12.963327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-08-23T22:20:14.362146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:20:14] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:20:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:20:14] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2013-08-23T22:20:14.598462+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-08-23T22:20:15.813174+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-08-23T22:20:15.831103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-08-23T22:24:29.867171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2013-08-23T22:24:29.866819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2013-08-23T22:24:34.878609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38733 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-23T22:24:37.305692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:24:37] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
2013-08-23T22:24:37.305692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:24:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-08-23T22:24:37.305872+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-08-23 22:24:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=38733
2013-08-23T22:24:37.368038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:38733
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 162.195.72.6 at 2013-08-23 22:24:37 +0000
2013-08-23T22:24:37.956733+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 162.195.72.6 at 2013-08-23 22:24:37 +0000
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915852+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=guarded-gorge-3135.herokuapp.com fwd="162.195.72.6" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=13967ms status=404 bytes=1351
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914574+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.914966+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2013-08-23T22:24:51.915113+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-08-23T22:24:52.238356+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=guarded-gorge-3135.herokuapp.com fwd="162.195.72.6" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Comment: run `heroku logs` and post output here.

Comment: I added the heroku logs by editing my earlier comment. Pleave view above.

Comment: You didn't set a root route.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have an error - just that you haven't set a route for the root. ie. something like this in `routes.rb` `root 'home#index'`.

PS. Note that Rails 4 does something weird in production - it behaves differently to development mode, and expects an explicit root route defined.

Comment: Thank you, That was the problem. With Rails 4, once the app is deployed an explicit root has to be set as you've mentioned.